# Refactoring Code While It Is In Active Development

Tags: git, refactoring

Well, this is a common sense question and I am sure this is not possible but I got into a debate with my teammate(who said it is possible) today and wanted an input from the experienced heads

> Is is possible to refactor code that is in active development?

Here is the scenario.

You are refactoring `function_A` and as part of active development, your teammate is working on `function_A` and adding more lines of code. You are using `git` so your refactored `function_A` will be merged with your teammate's updated `function_A` that has say, 15 new lines of code distributed randomly which were added as part of active development.

Comment: Git might not be able to manually merge the changes for you, and you both might have to spend time together understanding how to incorporate both of your changes. That said, there should probably be some process in place to prevent this situation where one person is refactoring code that is being actively developed by another person; it does not sound like it is making efficient use of your team. This would more effectively be done during a code review phase.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the situation you describe, then you definitely need to refactor.

For the most part, your code should always be in a state that the probability of two people editing the same function tend to zero. The probability of two people editing the same file should be small. In well-written codebases, a new feature means a new file (since it's a new feature, why would it be mixed in with old features?).

Secondly, in general you should refactor things you're working on. Since you're working on it you're the best person to know how to restructure the code. Don't just blindly scan the entire code base looking for stuff to refactor unless you have nothing else to do.

Finally, depending on who you ask, 15 lines of code should be a complete function. Some people consider adding 15 lines to a function as not making sense since the 15 lines by itself qualifies as a function. But not everyone thinks this way. Still, it's a good rule of thumb to aspire to even if you don't follow it 100% of the time.

So it's entirely possible to refactor code in active development. Indeed, the philosophy behind test-driven development means you always refactor the code you're writing. The three steps of writing code is even called red-green-refactor and you're supposed to cycle through red-green-refactor every 5 to 10 minutes. But doing it the way you describe would of course cause a lot of merge conflicts.